# Flash messages in Devise and Twitter bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, devise, flash-message

I have installed Devise but there is no flash messages are shown and I am also using twitter bootstrap , how can I make them appear ?

Comment: You have not shown any code or provided any details for us to help you. Please start by telling us exactly what you tried and even post some code, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the bootstrap documentation... You have to add some lines in Application.html.erb to enable flash notifications i guess...

something similar to this

```
<%= render partial: "shared/flash_messages", flash: flash %>
```

and define the style and contents of flash messages in shared/_flash_messages.html.erb
(its placed under shared as flash messages are applicable throughout ur app..

[Check this github gist..](https://gist.github.com/roberto/3344628)

This is jus an example and it most probably is inbuilt in Bootstrap... check the documentation properly :)

Hope this helps..